# Grep for a word after matching a pattern and print

Tags: linux, shell

Say I have a file name foo.txt, and it contains the following information.

```
Notification are enabled
Notification:445
Mode: valid
Bookmark are enabled
Bookmarks:556
Mode: Invalid
Question are enabled
Question:667
Mode: Unknown
```

I want to grep/awk/sed the below information.
I need the result like

```
                   "Notification is Valid"
                   "Bookmark is Invalid"
                   "Question is Unknown"
```

If you need anything else please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Could you show us what you tried so far ?

Comment: `grep` is line-oriented, so you'll need more than just `grep` to solve the problem. Have you considered writing a short script to parse the file instead?

Comment: @Tuxdude-I tried using cat foo.txt| grep 'Notification:445\|Mode:' but it's returning all the Modes, but I want immediate Mode value of Notification ! Can you please help?

Comment: @nneonneo - I'm at initial state of learning shell scripting !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you want correctly, something like this might work:

```
awk '/enabled/{g=$1}/Mode:/{printf "%s is %s\n",g,$NF}' foo.txt
```

At least that should work given the example you've given. If you have to deal with `disabled` or anything else other than `enabled`, that'll make it a little more complex...

Comment: @twalberg- Thanks for answering. That is working for notification. I'm unable to use the same command for Bookmark which is returning all Modes...Can you help?     And also what if all are enabled ? and how can we return all those values? thanks.

Comment: That command should, given the example you've given, print all three of them. It works by remembering the first word of any line that contains the word `enabled`, then when a line matches `Mode:`, it prints the remembered word and the last field of the `Mode` line. Of course, if your actual input doesn't really look like that, your results will vary.

Comment: Then perhaps you need to post a real example of your input `foo.txt`. The script above, when presented with the example text you gave, produces exactly the output you wanted, except for the quote marks. I can't tell what's going wrong if I can't see what's different about the input...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming foo.txt and we want to extract the 1st and last words of every 3 lines that contains 6 "groups" of separated by space of \n char expressions, using xargs:

```
xargs -n6 < foo.txt
```

"linearize" the content, and gives:

```
Notification are enabled Notification:445 Mode: valid
Bookmark are enabled Bookmarks:556 Mode: Invalid
Question are enabled Question:667 Mode: Unknown
```

pipe this content to awk:

```
xargs -n6 < foo.txt | awk '{print $1" is "$6}'
```

it gives something, I guess, closed to what you are looking for:

```
Notification is valid
Bookmark is Invalid
Question is Unknown
```

HTH